# Access td elments inside li tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

i am trying to access td element which is inside an li tag .my code is like this

```
$(document).on("click",".open",function(){
  var $url;
          var $row = $(this).closest("tr"),         
    $tds = $row.find("td:nth-child(1)"); 
$.each($tds, function() {               
      $("#file").val(($(this).text()));
      $("#type").val("open");
 });
```

Servlet Code :

```
 sb.append("<ul class=\"child\">");
          if(listOfFiles!=null){
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {


    sb.append("<tr>");

     if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
        sb.append("<li class=\"file\">");
        sb.append("<td>"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+"</td>");
        sb.append("<td><button class=\"open\">OPEN</button></td>");
        sb.append("<td><button class = \"edit\">EDIT</button></td>");
        sb.append("<td><button class =\"share\">SHARE</button></td>");
        sb.append("<td><button class =\"log\">VIEW LOG</button></td>");
        sb.append("</li>");

      } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        sb.append("<li class=\"folder false\">"+listOfFiles[i].getName()+"</li>");

      }
 sb.append("</tr>");
    }
sb.append("</ul>");
}
```

I don't whether iam doing it correctly.Iam calling an ajax call to sevlet and append the Responsetext to an li tag.Then i try to access the td element inside it but it is not working .I don't if it is good practice to put td inside li so Please Help..
Thanks in Advance

Comment: The markup is invalid.

Comment: Your first step is valid markup. `tr` cannot be a direct child of `ul`, but that's what the code above does. Similarly, `li` cannot be a child of `tr`, nor can `td` be a child of `li`. Browsers will reorganize to try to make it work, but the way they do that may not be what you expect.

Comment: can you suggest an alternative ,i want to have 4 button inside li tag

Comment: @AntonyVibin - I recommend stepping back from what you're doing and working through some basic HTML tutorials.

Comment: @AntonyVibin Invalid markup will work sometimes but it is a really bad practice and should be validated. This is necessary to eliminate problems in future.

Comment: ok i will Thanks